# <c:forEach> and <h:commandLink> not able to work together?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Hi I have a jsp page like this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Compact Output</title>
</head>
<body>
  <f:view>
    <h:form>
      <c:forEach items="${bean.itemlist}" var="item">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="panel1">
      <h2><c:out value="${item.displayName}" /></h2>
          <img src="<c:out value="${item.thumbnailURI}"/>" height="600" width="800" />    
          <h:commandLink action="#{bean.action1}" value="Details">
            <f:param name="selecteddisplayName"  value="#{item.displayName}" />
          </h:commandLink>
        </h:panelGrid>
      </c:forEach>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

I put

```
        <h:commandLink action="#{bean.action1}" value="Details">
            <f:param name="selecteddisplayName"  value="#{item.displayName}" />
          </h:commandLink>
```

inside the  tag, but when click the link, the #{bean.action1} got called, but the parameter item.displayName is not passed to the controller. I tried to change it to ${item.displayName} then I got compile error "value" does not support runtime expressions.

What is wrong with my jsp page?

In my controller I have defined private String selecteddisplayName and getter/setters.

Maybe  can not work together with ?

Answer (score 0):

if u want to set values in property than

try  `<f:setPropertyActionListener value="" target=""/>`
instead of  `<f:param name="selecteddisplayName"  value="#{item.displayName}" />`

Comment: I tried it didn't work. With <f:param> in the bean the value is null, with <f:setPropertyActionListener> in the bean the value is "". Not much difference...

Comment: I guess it's problem of mix use of ${} and #{}, when expression #{item.displayName} is evaluated, the value is not there yet, the generated html can prove this. You can see the value is "" in html.

<a href="#" onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('j_id_jsp_1701097890_1','j_id_jsp_1701097890_1:j_id_jsp_1701097890_3',null,[['selecteddisplayName','']]);">Details</a></td></tr>

Comment: However when I change it to ${item.displayName}, eclipse will give compile error "value" does not support runtime expressions. when running on server I got error: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions. How to resolve this?